# Problems with PKRevealController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to use PKRevealController with Storyboard. This is how my AppDelegate looks at startup

```
MainNavController* navController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainNavController"];

MainViewController* mainViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
LeftViewController* leftViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftViewController"];


PKRevealController *revealController = [PKRevealController revealControllerWithFrontViewController:navController  leftViewController:leftViewController];

revealController.animationDuration = 0.25;
revealController.delegate = self;

self.window.rootViewController = revealController;
```

So that seems to work fine, and the App Launches with no problems, but when I swipe to the right, the left view controller shows up and then crashes with this error:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PKAnimation pk_identifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an importation error. Check here https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController/blob/master/Documentation/USAGE.md to see how to import correctly, if you import it as a static library make sure to reproduce all steps!